# Why the output is correct with commented return

Tags: c

recently I have been exercising on Codility and I have managed to accomplish the exercise Passing Cars.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int PassingCars(int someArray[], int N)
{
        if(N == 1)
        return 0;

        int counter = 0, result = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
                if(someArray[i] == 0)
                        ++counter;

                if(someArray[i] == 1)
                {
                        result += counter;
                        if(result > 1e9)
                                return -1;
                }
        }

        //return result;
}

int main()
{
        int arrOne[] = {0, 1, 0, 1, 1};

        printf("%d\n", PassingCars(arrOne, sizeof(arrOne)/sizeof(arrOne[0])));

        return 0;
}
```

Even though return of result is commented the output is correct. How?

Comment: The output is pure coincidence, because it is undefined behaviour. On of the possible UB cases is: It seems to work. Try re-compiling with high optimisation level and you'll most probably see one of the other possible outcomes.

Comment: @tofro indeed with -O3 flag the result is -1. I envy your intuition, how can one make like that :D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Your CPU does not care about missing "returns"

To execute a C program its [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) has to be compiled/translated by the [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) into [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code).

Machine code is just a bunch of [instruction that the CPU can execute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) one by one,
to causing the value of [registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) or memory locations to change.
When a part of these execution should handover a value to another section,
that gets executed subsequent, it has to pass these value via a register.
But when the "return value register" is not set, i may contain some random value of a prior instruction result. Your CPU does not care about missing hand-overs between two code sections, because it does only care about executing instruction one by one, without knowing what the larger logic of these instructions was ment to be.

It seams that in your case that the old value in such a register is coincidentally the same value as what which should be set/returned in/from `PassingCars` as a result. Probably because you have code that calculated the length of your input array and that value is used during the execution often, which is actually the correct result of the function to return.

To check this you could compile your source code into assembly code and reverse engineer it:

```sh
$ gcc -S ./main.c
$ cat ./main.s
        .file   "main.c"
        .text
        .globl  PassingCars
        .type   PassingCars, @function
PassingCars:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        endbr64
.
.
.
```

But this is rather time consuming.

## Avoid missing return value with Compiler Warnings

To avoid problems like this in the future you can utilize compilier warnings like `-Wall` for example:

```sh
gcc -Wall ./main.c
./main.c: In function ‘PassingCars’:
./main.c:23:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   23 | }
      | ^
```

Here is a link to the documentation about the [gcc warning options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).